# Can't seem to scrape the website "Forbes" properly

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the links and titles of the articles on the frontpage of the website https://www.forbes.com/ .

I'm not proficient in html, but I'm been following some beautfiul soup tutorials and have been getting by with the knowledge I'm picking up along the way.

Here is what I have so far:

```
source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.forbes.com').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')  # Tried 'html.parser' as well


##print(soup.findAll('div',{'class':"c-entry-box--compact c-entry-box--compact--article"}))

for url  in soup.findAll('a',{'class':"exit_trigger_set"}):
     print (url.get('href'))
```

Inspecting the site's html, I seem to have the class and  'a' (not sure what you call 'a' in this case) correct.

However, instead of getting all the links of the articles on the frontpage, I'm only getting one.

`https://www.amazon.com/Intelligent-REIT-Investor-Wealth-Investment/dp/1119252717`

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you.

EDIT:

This seems to find some of the top stories but I don't know how to pull out the links only

```
for i in soup.findAll('h4', {'class': "editable editable-hed"}):
    print (i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

source = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.forbes.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

lst = []
for i in soup.findAll('h4', {'class': "editable editable-hed"}):
    title = i.text
    link = i.find('a')['href'][2:]

    title = title.replace('\t','')
    title = title.replace('\n','')
    title = title.strip()

    lst.append({'title':title, 'link':link})

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(lst)
```

And you get 15 articles and their links.

Comment: Wow, this seems to work great. (Sorry for the late reply, I didn't get a chance to look at my script till now).   I'm going to read your answer more carefully and see if I have any more questions. Thank you so much.

Comment: Quick question: Why is the 2 here (after href) necessary   `link = i.find('a')['href'][2:]`

Comment: It's because the links, for some reason have the following format: "//www.forbes.com/sites/maggiemcgrath/2017/02/08/trump-vs-retailers-a-timeline-of-corporate-reactions-to-consumer-boycotts/".. Note the two slashes in front. The [2:] just ignores these two slashes.